# Comparing XML using a Linq to xml query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
<User>
  <Username> Admin </Username>
  <Password> 123 </Password>
<User>
</Users>
```

I need to look for a variable in username elements when I find it, then I have to compare its password with the one I have in another variable and check if they match.

What are good way to do the following ? If you need to change the format of the XML file it's no problem as long as it contains username / password.

Comment: You should not be storing a plain text password in an XML file. If you don't want to deal with a real database you should check out something like SQLite.

Comment: I'm planing on using MD5 Hash I won't store the password as plain text but that's not an issue since I have it figured out.

Comment: this is pretty simple thing that google would solve

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't store passwords in plain XML; however, I think this is the kind of comparison you're looking for:

```
var userSought = "userA";
var passwordSought = "1234";

XDocument xml = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("Users",
        new XElement("User",
            new XElement("Username", "Admin"),
            new XElement("Password", "123")),
        new XElement("User",
            new XElement("Username", "userA"),
            new XElement("Password", "123"))
        ));

var userMatch = (from userElement in xml.Element("Users").Elements("User")
                  where userElement.Element("Username").Value == userSought
                  select new
                  {
                      Username = userElement.Element("Username").Value,
                      Password = userElement.Element("Password").Value
                  }).FirstOrDefault();

if(userMatch.Username == userSought && userMatch.Password == passwordSought)
    Console.WriteLine(userSought + " matches password " + passwordSought);
else
    Console.WriteLine(userSought + " has password " + userMatch.Password + " but is expected to be " + passwordSought);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick I'll test the following today when I get on my laptop.